# LEFT JOINS create to much rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relative simple query here that is not returning the expected number of rows. I think that the following query should be working correctly for my case, but I must am missing something essential here to make sure not all rows are shown multiple times.!

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color, g.value AS gender, p.value AS price
FROM   products p
LEFT JOIN product_fields c ON c.product_id = p.id AND c.name = 'color'
LEFT JOIN product_fields g ON g.product_id = p.id AND g.name = 'gender'
LEFT JOIN product_fields pp ON pp.product_id = p.id AND pp.name = 'price'
```

Comment: Have you tried `DISTINCT`?

Comment: I have tried using DISTINCT, but I could not make it work for this problem. How would you suggest I use the DISTINCT function to make this work correctly?

Comment: try give us some test data and explain why you don't expect a result to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you name table `products AS p` and then later also `product_fields AS p`. Try this:

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color, g.value AS gender, p.value AS price
FROM   products p
LEFT JOIN product_fields c ON c.product_id = p.id AND c.name = 'color'
LEFT JOIN product_fields g ON g.product_id = p.id AND g.name = 'gender'
LEFT JOIN product_fields pr ON pr.product_id = p.id AND pr.name = 'price'
```

Note, that you use `LEFT JOIN`, which allows a match NULL values. maybe all you need to do is changing to `INNER JOIN`?

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color, g.value AS gender, p.value AS price
FROM   products p
INNER JOIN product_fields c ON c.product_id = p.id AND c.name = 'color'
INNER JOIN product_fields g ON g.product_id = p.id AND g.name = 'gender'
INNER JOIN product_fields pr ON pp.product_id = p.id AND pp.name = 'price'
```

Comment: Sorry this was my mistake from making my code into somewhat pseudo code... I have edited my question.

Comment: i see. so this is not your problem after all. but it seems that you also should use the p in the left join

Answer (score 2):

A LEFT JOIN includes all records from the first table and all matching records from the second table, assuming the query does not exclude null values from the second table.

But an INNER JOIN excludes from the results set any records that do not exist in both tables.

So this might help  you:

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color, g.value AS gender, p.value AS price
FROM   products p
INNER JOIN product_fields c ON c.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN product_fields g ON g.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN product_fields pp ON pp.product_id = products.id
WHERE c.name = 'color' AND g.name = 'gender' AND pp.name = 'price'
```

For differences between types of join [MySQL Joins](http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2010/12/25/mysql-join-cross-inner-outer-left-right-full/)

Comment: The INNER JOIN solved my problem. Thanks! More of the same solutions, can accept only one.

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` will get unmatched rows that doesn't match the condition of the `name = ..`,  thats why you get much rows, I would suggest using `INNER JOIN` instead, or if you need to use `LEFT JOIN` you can do this:

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color, g.value AS gender, p.value AS price
FROM   products p
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT *
   FROM product_fields
   WHERE name = 'color'
) AS c ON c.product_id = products.id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM product_fields
   WHERE name = 'gender'
) AS g ON g.product_id = products.id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM product_fields
   WHERE name = 'price'
) AS pp ON pp.product_id = products.id
```

Comment: The INNER JOIN solved my problem. Thanks! More of the same solutions, can accept only one.

Comment: @Hugo - You're welcome :) Feel free to accept any answer, it doesn't matter. But, I think you should accept one of the other answers, they were faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

You put the alias `p` for the table `products` but in the joins you use the table name, try using the alias on the join to see if it resolves your problem:

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color, g.value AS gender, p.value AS price
FROM   products p
LEFT JOIN product_fields c ON c.product_id = p.id AND c.name = 'color'
LEFT JOIN product_fields g ON g.product_id = p.id AND g.name = 'gender'
LEFT JOIN product_fields pp ON pp.product_id = p.id AND pp.name = 'price'
```

Comment: Good suggestion I have looked over that and changed it, but did not seem to resolve my issue. :(